# PHP SimpleXMLElement как добавить пространство имён?

Tags: php

Нужно привести к подобному виду
Value
При добавлении узла:

```
$xml->addChild('namespace:tag','value','namespace');
```

Получается что-то типа

```
<namespace:tag xmlns:namespace="namespace">value</namespace:tag>
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то? Что именно не получается?

Comment: Нужно чтоб на выходе был такой вариант:
  <namespace:tag>value</namespace:tag>

Comment: Эм... а чем то, что вы получаете отличается от того что вам нужно? Вопрос то в чем?

Comment: Отличается на выходе мне нужен следующий вид:
    <namespace:tag>value</namespace:tag>
А получается :
    <namespace:tag xmlns:namespace="namespace">value</namespace:tag>